# Does PostgreSQL still need Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (vcredist 2010)?

Tags: postgresql

I have used the zip archive of binaries of an old Windows version of PostgreSQL that required `Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (vcredist 2010)` to be installed.

I would like to know if the Windows binaries of the newer version of PostgreSQL still need the `vcredist 2010`. I didn't find anything about this in the download pages of the binaries (https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/
and https://www.enterprisedb.com/download-postgresql-binaries).

Note: I prefer to use the binaries instead of the standard installer to include PostgreSQL as part of my application installer.

Comment: Yes, Postgres still needs vcredist. But you can just include the DLL with your application installer. Another option might be to use the binaries from [BigSQL](https://www.bigsql.org/package-manager.jsp) which are built using gcc rather then Visual C

Comment: Thank you, but which DLL to include? I use to include the vcredist installer and make a silent install of it. But I would like to change it, because my software is being considered as unwanted from Google Adwords and I'm suspecting that vcredist is the cause. Here is a diagnostic site that find malicious indicators in vcredist installer: https://www.reverse.it/sample/8162b2d665ca52884507ede19549e99939ce4ea4a638c537fa653539819138c8?environmentId=100

Comment: To my knowledge it's only `MSVCR120.DLL`

Comment: BigSQL seems to be interesting. I would like to try it, but it seems not to have a 32 bits version. Some users of my software still use Windows XP.

Comment: @viniciussss have you found any solution for this problem?

Comment: @Dragon No. I ended up embedding Vcredist in an Inno Setup installer along with my software and PostgreSQL binaries.